# If method enum parameter is certain value require optional parameter and show a compiler error

Tags: c#

I have the following enum and method defined. I want to require the user to provide the `error` string, which is an optional parameter, if the log level is `Error`. Is there a way to detect the `error` string is missing present this as a compiler error when the `LogLevel` is `Error`. Using Visual Studio.

```
public enum LogLevel {
    Info,
    Error
}
public void Log(LogLevel level, string message, string error = "") { .. do stuff .. }
```

This is an invalid call and should give the user a compiler error:

```
Log(LogLevel.Error, "Some message"); // no error string provided, throwing compiler error
```

Comment: This is not possible compile-time with enums. An alternative would be using an interface `ILogLevel`, and an implementation of that interface `Error : ILogLevel`, followed by making two methods `Log` - one that takes `Error` and `string`, and one that takes `Info`. It's not quite the same though. You could also consider making this a run-time check instead.

Comment: You can also consider writing a pre-build event that calls a script that validates all your code for stuff like this. Or you could write your own compiler.

Comment: What if you pass a variable for `level`?  Like `Log(myCurrentLoggingLevel, "Some message")`

Comment: If you require the log level to be known at compile time, change the API to two different functions:  `LogInfo` and `LogError`

Comment: you cannot have a compile tlme behavior (a compiler error) with something that can depends on a runtime value. e.g `LogLevel x = GetLogLevelSomehow(); Log(x, "some message");` If logging error requires different parameters as input, create different metods; `LogInfo(string message); LogError(string message, string error);`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: A code validator might be able to do this, but not the compiler itself.  Not sure what the custom rule would look like.  Maybe someone will know.